# Problems with socket.io over https, using nginx as proxy

Tags: nginx, https, socket.io

I have a very weird problem with `socket.io` and I was hoping someone can help me out.

For some reason **few clients** cannot connect to the server no matter what, when I am using `https`.
I am getting the following error code: `ERR_CRYPTO_OPERATION_FAILED` (see the detailed log below)

Again, most of the time the connection is perfectly fine, only some (random) clients seem to have this problem.

I have created a super simple `server.js` and `client.js` to make it easy to test.

I am using `socket.io@2.4.1`, and `socket.io-client@2.4.0`

Unfortunately version `3.x.x` is not an option.

The OS is **Ubuntu 18.04**, both on the server, and the client side.

#### Nginx:

```sh
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.domain.com;
        return 301 https://example.domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name example.domain.com;

        ssl_certificate /path/to/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/cert.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

        location /
        {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        }

        location /socket.io {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
                proxy_read_timeout 30s;
                proxy_send_timeout 30s;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io;
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;
        }
}
```

#### client.js:

```js
const client = io.connect("https://example.domain.com", {
    origins: '*:*',
    transportOptions: {
        polling: {
            extraHeaders: {
                'Authorization': token
            }
        }
    },
});
```

Tried adding `secure: true`, `reconnect: true`, and `rejectUnauthorized : false`, but no difference.
Also, I tested it **with** and **without** the `transportOptions`.

#### server.js:

```js
const port = 5000;
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port: ${port}`);
});

const io = socket(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("Client connected", socket.id);
});
```

Of course, when I remove the redirect in `nginx` and use plain old `http` to connect, then everything is fine.

When I run `DEBUG=* node client.js`, I get the following:

```
socket.io-client:url parse https://example.domain.com/ +0ms
socket.io-client new io instance for https://example.domain.com/ +0ms
socket.io-client:manager readyState closed +0ms
socket.io-client:manager opening https://example.domain.com/ +1ms
engine.io-client:socket creating transport "polling" +0ms
engine.io-client:polling polling +0ms
engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr poll +0ms
engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr open GET: https://example.domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NVowV1t&b64=1 +2ms
engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr data null +2ms
engine.io-client:socket setting transport polling +61ms
socket.io-client:manager connect attempt will timeout after 20000 +66ms
socket.io-client:manager readyState opening +3ms
engine.io-client:socket socket error {"type":"TransportError","description":{"code":"ERR_CRYPTO_OPERATION_FAILED"}} +12ms
socket.io-client:manager connect_error +9ms
socket.io-client:manager cleanup +1ms
socket.io-client:manager will wait 1459ms before reconnect attempt +3ms
engine.io-client:socket socket close with reason: "transport error" +6ms
engine.io-client:polling transport not open - deferring close +74ms
socket.io-client:manager attempting reconnect +1s
...
```

Searching for `ERR_CRYPTO_OPERATION_FAILED` error, only leads me to the [node.js errors page](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_err_crypto_operation_failed)
which has only the following description:

> Added in: v15.0.0
> A crypto operation failed for an otherwise unspecified reason.

I am using Let's Encrypt certificate.

I don't get it. If it is an SSL issue, why am I getting this error only for few clients?
Maybe I am missing something in `nginx`?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've seem similar error with `node-apn`. My solution was to downgrade to nodejs v14. Maybe give that a try?

Answer (score 1):

two step

1. the version of node must be 14.x
2. add this config when connect  `rejectUnauthorized: false`